# in Ember, how to add item to CollectionView dynamically, I create one jsbin, but i saw duplicated items/

Tags: javascript, ember.js, collectionview

How to add item to CollectionView dynamically in Emberjs?
I see every time I add one item to the controller, the collectionView renders again ,just append to the one just rendered. 
Here is the jsbin link  http://jsbin.com/iBaC/1/edit

Comment: I have 2 ways to solve this. The one is removeAllChildren(); The other one is just render the last item every time.  I dont know if there's any normal way??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code you already have as well next to jsbin?

Comment: @user2699589 I did not understand the question, can you please elaborate what you are trying to acheive

Comment: if you click the same item twice ,you will see 4 views rendered. what i want is to open menus in tab content.one menu can be opened more than one time.

Comment: I just wonder why does it have to render all items again every time when I use "this.addObject(item);" to add item to content.